# Llamadas al sistema con ficheros

Tags: c

Tengo un código cuya misión es copiar un fuente en un destino. La cuestión es que, al compilar me advierte de que en la línea 38 se realiza una asignación desde un entero a un puntero sin un moldeo y no sé como arreglarlo.

Además, al ejecutarlo en linux me da un Violación de segmento 'core' generado. Igualmente, en CodeBlocks se aborta la ejecución.

Éste es mi código:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int copia (char * ruta_fue, char * ruta_des){
    int fd_fue,fd_des,leidos,escritos;
    void * dato;
    if(access(ruta_des,F_OK)==0){
        fd_fue = open(ruta_des,O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
    } else {
        fd_fue = creat(ruta_des,0600);
    }
    fd_fue = open(ruta_fue,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd_fue<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Ha fallado la apertura de %s\n", ruta_fue);
        perror("");
        return -1;
    }
    while( ( leidos = read(fd_fue,&dato,sizeof(int) ) ) > 0 ){
        if( ( escritos = write(fd_des,dato,leidos) ) < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Ha fallado la escritura de %s\n", ruta_des);
            perror("");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    close(fd_fue);
    close(fd_des);
    printf("La copia se ha realizado bien");
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char * ruta_fue,ruta_des;
    ruta_fue = (char *)argv[1];
    ruta_des = (char *)argv[2];
    copia(ruta_fue,ruta_des);

    struct stat info_fue, info_des;
    stat(ruta_fue,&info_fue);
    stat(ruta_des,&info_des);
    if(info_fue.st_size!=info_des.st_size){
        fprintf(stderr,"Los tamaños de %s y %s no coinciden",ruta_fue,ruta_des);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Los tamaños de %s y %s son iguales",ruta_fue,ruta_des);
}
```

Nota: la línea 38 es `ruta_des = (char *)argv[2];`.

Answer (score 3):

Por norma general intenta compilar con los flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, y luego intenta arreglar, los errores uno por uno empezando por el primero que salga.

Por ejemplo, de tu aplicación (esto deberías haberlo adjuntado en la pregunta):

```
 In function 'int main(int, char**)':
38:14: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
39:28: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
43:28: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
45:80: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 4 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
48:67: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
 At global scope:
35:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
```

Vemos que estas intentando asignar un char a un char*. Esto ocurre porque tienes la declaración de las variables de forma incorrecta:

```
char * ruta_fue,ruta_des;
```

- `ruta_fue` es un char*
- `ruta_des` es un char !!!

Cambialo por:

```
char *ruta_fue, *ruta_des;
```

Otro problema que tienes es que no compruebas si el número de parámetros que recibe el programa `argc` coincide con lo que tu esperas: (3 o más) ya que los accesos `argc[1]` y `argc[2]` pueden no ser válidos.
Protege esa región comprobando si argc es lo que esperas y sinó acaba el programa:

```
if (argc < 3) return -1;
```

Otro error que tienes es:

```
23:50: warning: 'fd_des' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

Deberías inicializar ese file descriptor antes de llamar a write

Comment: `if (argc < 3) return -1;` está bien, pero antes de retornar mejor imprimir un mensaje, si no, nos quedamos en ayunas :-)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que declaración

```
char * ruta_fue,ruta_des;
```

es equivalente a

```
char * ruta_fue;
char ruta_des;
```

Lo que quieres, en cambio, es

```
char * ruta_fue;
char * ruta_des;
```

o, si quieres ponerlo en una línea:

```
char *ruta_fue, *ruta_des;
```

En la declaración `char * x;` imagina que el asterisco va pegado a la variable, no al tipo: se lee como  `char (* x)`, que a su vez se lee como "*`x` apunta a un `char`*" - o "*`x` dereferenciado es de tipo `char`*"). Por lo tanto 
`char * x, z ;` significa "*`x` apunta a un `char` y `z` es un `char`*"

( [Detalles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282217/277304) - en inglés).